# Please suggest approaches and code to solve the defined problem statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

```
x   y   z   amount  absolute_amount
121 abc def  500       500
131 fgh xyz -800       800
121 abc xyz  900       900
131 fgh ijk  800       800
141 obc pqr  500       500
151 mbr pqr -500       500
141 obc pqr -500       500
151 mbr pqr  900       900
```

I need to find the duplicate rows in the dataset where the x and y are same, with conditions being-

> 1. sum(amount) !=0
> 2. abs(sum(amount)) != absolute_amount

I tried grouping them and the code i used in R is working but i need it to work in python

```
logic1 <- tablename %>%
group_by('x','y')%>%
filter(n()>1 && sum(`amount`) != 0 && abs(sum(`amount`)) != absolute_amount)
```

Expected output

```
x   y   z   amount  absolute_amount
121 abc def  500       500
121 abc xyz  900       900
151 mbr pqr -500       500
151 mbr pqr  900       900
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please edit your post to share what you've tried and how/why it didn't work (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform` with [`groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to return sum transformed for each group and then compare the 2 conditions you have:

```
c=df.groupby(['x','y'])['amount'].transform('sum')
df[c.ne(0) & c.abs().ne(df.absolute_amount)]
```

---

```
     x    y    z  amount  absolute_amount
0  121  abc  def     500              500
2  121  abc  xyz     900              900
5  151  mbr  pqr    -500              500
7  151  mbr  pqr     900              900
```